# Setting automatically created taxonomy terms using rules module

Tags: rules

I am using the rules module to automatically create a taxonomy term when i create content of a certain type.  I would also like to automatically populate the taxonomy term reference in the the created content. I have tried many different configurations using the set data function in rules however it does not ever set the taxonomy term to the the new-term which is created.

Is there any way that this operation can be carried out using rules.

I have exported the rule for you to take a look at.

```
/**
 * @file
 * advertising_region_creator.rules_defaults.inc
 */

/**
 * Implements hook_default_rules_configuration().
 */
function advertising_region_creator_default_rules_configuration() {
  $items = array();
  $items['rules_auto_taxonomy'] = entity_import('rules_config', '{ "rules_auto_taxonomy" : {
      "LABEL" : "Auto Taxonomy",
      "PLUGIN" : "reaction rule",
      "REQUIRES" : [ "rules" ],
      "ON" : [ "node_insert" ],
      "IF" : [
        { "node_is_of_type" : {
            "node" : [ "node" ],
            "type" : { "value" : { "savings_viewer" : "savings_viewer" } }
          }
        }
      ],
      "DO" : [
        { "entity_create" : {
            "USING" : {
              "type" : "taxonomy_term",
              "param_name" : "[node:title]",
              "param_vocabulary" : "2"
            },
            "PROVIDE" : { "entity_created" : { "new_term" : "New Term" } }
          }
        },
        { "data_set" : {
            "data" : [ "node:field-savings-viewer-region" ],
            "value" : [ "new-term" ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }');
  return $items;
}
```

I apologize if this is posted in the wrong format I am new to all of this but will keep trying to get better.

Comment: Adding your rule export here may help better understand your problem.

Comment: create term pro-grammatically  with rules using PHP code.

Comment: I have pasted the exported rule i hope this gives a better understanding of what I am trying to do.

Comment: I am unsure on how to create the rule using PHP at this point. if there is any resources or help you could provide on using PHP to create the rule  it will be greatly appreciated. the only concept I could think of is to hard code it in the database using an edit command. However I something tells me that this is not what you had in mind monymirza

Answer (score 2):

Simply add a autocomplete taxonomy field to the content type and when node saves, rule to set data into this field. Taxonomy module will then create the new term if it does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

If you enable 'PHP filter' module (in the Core package) you will unlock an additional action rule 'Execute custom php code'. There you can use drupal API commands to both create and attach the terms. (Better to do the creation as well, since then you can get the ID of the created term.)

From here it depends if you have drupal 6 or 7. The code is for 7, but should get you started with 6 as well.

The final code would be something like this, but I have not tested it.

```
$term = new stdClass(); // Make a new term object
$term->name = $name; // New term name
$term->vid = $vid; // Term's vocabulary ID
taxonomy_term_save($term); // Save the term

$node->taxonomy[] = $term->tid; // Attach the taxonomy term ID of saved term
node_save($node); // Save the node again with the term
```

**Update**

- Make sure that you try to run this code on the event 'after saving a new node', otherwise there won't be a node id yet.
- If that does not work, try using only `$node->taxonomy` without the `[]`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I enabled the PHP filter module and then inserted the above code into the execute PHP command action.

Comment: sorry about the last comment...
I entered the code into the execute php script action and changed the vid to my vocabulary ID.  It adds the taxonomy term however does not attach it to the node content.

Comment: Updated the answer.

Comment: I do have token enabled and i can save the taxonomy as the [node:nid], which tells me that rules is reading the [node:nid] string.  However it still will not update the newly saved node content to attach the term.

Comment: I see... I just remembered that rules automatically gives you access to the $node variable. Try running with only the last 2 lines as in the edited example.

Comment: When I use only the last 2 lines I get a whole heap of db insert errors and the no datat is entered at all

Answer (score 0):

Neograph's answer is close, but I had two problems with it:

this is correct to create a new term (in a custom php rules action):

```
$term = new stdClass(); // Make a new term object
$term->name = $name; // New term name
$term->vid = $vid; // Term's vocabulary ID
taxonomy_term_save($term); // Save the term
```

but the below results in 1) not setting a term field on the node and 2) a pdo exception where it tries to insert a new node twice.

```
$node->taxonomy[] = $term->tid; // Attach the taxonomy term ID of saved term
node_save($node); // Save the node again with the term
```

so instead this works for me:

```
$node->field_myterm[LANGUAGE_NONE] =  array(array('tid' => $term->tid));
```

THEN instead of trying to save the node in php, add another action to the the rule: save entity (right after the php action).