# Assign Taxonomy Term from Text Field

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms, rules

I am auto generating taxonomy terms basis of a text field with rules. I need to auto assign the newly generated taxonomy term to the node basis of the text field. I have tried the [Rules Autotag](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules_autotag) as well as [Taxonomy Autotagger](https://www.drupal.org/project/autotag). With both the modules, it does not pick any taxonomy terms.

I am trying to assign the Taxonomy Terms with rules, however, with the "Set a Data Value" option, it does not give me the option to select a Text Field to assign the Value for the Term Reference Field.

Please advice, how to assign a Term Reference Value from a Text Field using Rules?

Thanks

Comment: Is  the text field is there in node itself or you are performing the auto generating taxonomy terms separately ?

Comment: Its within the node itself. I had to get the taxonomy terms generated for displaying related content.

Comment: In this case rules will only work when node is updated, it will not work on when node is inserted. You should use hook_node_insert to update the node one taxanomy is generated.

Comment: That's correct. The rule is set to assign the term to the field once the node is updated, however, that is not happening. For some reason, the terms are generated, however, it does not pick the relevant terms once the node is updated. I am not a coder, hence trying to use rules to get this working for me.

Comment: Similar [issue](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/64399/setting-automatically-created-taxonomy-terms-using-rules-module). Also check this [thread](https://www.drupal.org/node/1659190)

Comment: Thanks for the links @nit3ch. I did check them, I am not very sure where to input this code from  (http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/64399/setting-automatically-created-taxonomy-terms-using-rules-module) ?